# Weekly schedule control for recurrently tasks

Tags: c#, controls, schedule, fritzbox

Searching for a control in c# which can do the following:
Should be a chart, on top the hours (0-24) on the left the days (Mon-Sun). Then I want the user to set a schedule for the days in the week. E.g. first shift starts from Mo-Fr at 8:00 and ends on Mo-Do at 22:00 and on Fr on 16:00.

Fritz Box already have this control in their router systems, this is exactly what I searching for in C#:
[image: Fritz Box Time Scheduler]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there  is any native control you have for this.
May be you can do this with lost of customization in grid.
I would recommend you using infragistics controls for winforms/wpf
Here is link to something you are looking for.
https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/scheduling/schedule

I have used infragistics tools in past they are pretty customizableand you can do almost do anything with them.